# How to use products images from another server without downloading it into our application

Tags: magento2, product-import

I'm trying to import about 2L products into my Magento 2.2.5 store. I have images in another external server. I want to use the images from that external server instead of downloading from that server into my application. means, the catalog images src is from another server. How can I do that? please guide.

Comment: have you tried by putting the external url of image in product csv in image column i think it will automatically import images from remote location.